# Use the definition of limit to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\epsilon >0.$ We look at 
$$ |\frac{n^3}{3^n} -0|.$$

Do I reduce the equation by taking the natural logarithm to get $\frac{3}{n} < \epsilon$ ?

Or do I reduce the equation to $\frac{1}{1+2n} < \frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{2K} < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: The derivative of x^y with respect to x is yx^(y-1) .  The derivative of x^y with respect to y is x^y *ln(y). This is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks you to show that exponential functions grow faster than polynomial functions.

Taking the logarithm, you'd need to show that $\ln\left(\frac{n^3}{3^n}\right) = 3\ln(n) - n \ln(3) \to -\infty$, which is basically analogous to the original problem.

There are direct aproaches

$e^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{k!} > \frac{n^4}{4!}
\\ \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{e^n} < \frac{4!}{n^4}
\\ \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{n^3}{e^n} = n^3 \cdot \frac{1}{e^n} < n^3 \cdot \frac{4!}{n^4} = \frac{4!}{n} \,\, \to \,\, 0$

as $n \to \infty$.

Combine this with the fact that $e < 3$.

EDIT: If you haven't yet been introduced to $e$ in real analysis, here's another way, motivated by the fact that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty = \left(\frac{n^3}{3^n}\right)_{n=0}^\infty$ eventually decreases.

For $n > 3$ we have

$\quad \quad 3 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} < 3+\frac{3}{3}+ \frac{1}{3^2} < 6  < 2n
\\ \Longrightarrow 3n^2+3n+1 = n^2\cdot(3 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}) < n^2 
\cdot (2n) = 2n^3
\\ \Longrightarrow (n+1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 < n^3 + 2n^3 = 3n^3
\\ \Longrightarrow a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^3}{3^{n+1}} < \frac{3n^3}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{n^3}{3^n} = a_n$

Thus by the monotone convergence theorem $a_n$ converges to some non-negative limit $a$. It is easily seen that $a=0$ by considering the subsequence of terms $a_{3^k} = \frac{(3^k)^3}{3^{3^k}} = \frac{1}{3^{3^k-3k}}$. Surely as $k$ gets arbitrarily large, so does $3^k - 3k$, and hence $a_{3^k} \to 0$.

I admit there are still better ways to come to the desired result.

Comment: I have to use the definition of limit ( $| X_n -X| $) to show `that the limit is 0

Comment: You now know that $|\frac{n^3}{3^n}-0| = \frac{n^3}{3^n} < \frac{n^3}{e^n} < \frac{4!}{n}$. If you choose an $\varepsilon$, you can easily find $n$ large enough so that $\frac{4!}{n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: What if you haven't defined $e$ yet (as is common in early stages of R.A.) ?

Comment: I provided another way. I'm sure there are better ways. This just came to mind

Answer (score 0):

Write $\sqrt[6]{3}=1+r$. Then Bernoulli’s inequality gives
$$
(\sqrt[6]{3})^n=(1+r)^n\ge1+nr
$$
so
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt[6]{3})^n}\le\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+nr}\le\frac{1}{r\sqrt{n}}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{n^3}{3^n}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt[6]{3})^n}\right)^6
\le\frac{1}{r^6n^3}
$$
from which you should be able to proceed.

The same strategy proves that, for each integer $k\ge1$ and each real number $\alpha>1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k}{\alpha^n}=0
$$